# find rows where event occurs too often

Tags: sql

let's say I have a single table, with 3 columns

| ts | event_id | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t0 | e1 | s1 |
| t1 | e2 | s1 |
| t2 | e3 | s2 |
| t3 | e4 | s1 |
| t4 | e5 | s2 |
| t5 | e6 | s2 |
| t6 | e7 | s3 |
| t7 | e8 | s3 |

`ts` is a timestamp, and the table is basically a journal, where the events are appended only. each event is part of a session, that basically "groups" the events.

I need to find all the `session_id`s where the events occur "too often".
Basically I would like to find an sql expression that could help me group the rows by session_id, and in each group check the difference between two subsequent timestamps (so the first with the second, not the first with the third), and show me only the sessions where the delta is less than a fixed limit.

Is this achievable via sql?

Comment: What database and version? Because the best option uses a new-ish feature that isn't supported by a number of databases still in active use. For example, MySQL prior to 8.0, SQL Server prior to 2012 R2, sqlite prior 3.25, Access (any version), etc.

Comment: Be careful to understand how `datediff()` works if you use that function in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `LEAD()` (or `LAG()`) window function.

This is a basic example, but it won't be fully right for you yet, as we don't know which database you have (which can change, e.g. the `DATEDIFF()` syntax), what the minimum delta should be, how you want to handle `NULL`s, whether the `QUALIFY` keyword is available, etc...

```
DECLARE @minimumDeltaInSeconds Int = 60;

WITH nextTimestamps As (
    SELECT *,
       lead(ts) over (partition by session_id order by ts) as NextTs
    FROM [table]
)
SELECT *
FROM nextTimestamps
WHERE DATEDIFF(second, ts, NextTs) < @minimumDeltaInSeconds
```